# newlist empty on BeforeUpdate when using TDTM

Tags: trigger, tdtm

newList and oldList is empty when using HED TDTM - unsure why...

code snippet

```
global class GM_TDTM_OpportunitiesDuplicateFilter extends hed.TDTM_Runnable {
    global override hed.TDTM_Runnable.DmlWrapper run(
            List<SObject> newlist,
            List<SObject> oldlist,
            hed.TDTM_Runnable.Action triggerAction,
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult) {
```

log

```
00:21:58.59 (59832568)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[70]|Aggregations:0|SELECT Class__c, Object__c, Trigger_Action__c, Load_Order__c, Active__c, Asynchronous__c, Filter_Field__c, Filter_Value__c, User_Managed__c, Owned_by_Namespace__c, Usernames_to_Exclude__c FROM Trigger_Handler__c
00:21:58.59 (67786218)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[70]|Rows:55
00:21:58.59 (510926647)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
00:21:58.59 (511028048)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[42]|Bytes:17
00:21:58.59 (511058538)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[42]|Bytes:5
00:21:58.59 (511074283)|METHOD_ENTRY|[44]|01p5e000001g6JO|hed.TDTM_Runnable.TDTM_Runnable()
00:21:58.59 (511081657)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[44]
00:21:58.59 (511095347)|METHOD_EXIT|[44]|hed.TDTM_Runnable
00:21:58.59 (511114273)|CONSTRUCTOR_ENTRY|[EXTERNAL]|01p5e000001g6JO|<init>()|hed.TDTM_Runnable
00:21:58.59 (511209723)|CONSTRUCTOR_EXIT|[EXTERNAL]|01p5e000001g6JO|<init>()|hed.TDTM_Runnable
00:21:58.59 (511224643)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
00:21:58.59 (516556184)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[372]|Aggregations:0|select RecordType.DeveloperName from Opportunity where ID in :compListIDs
00:21:58.59 (523843179)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[372]|Rows:1
00:21:58.59 (626682841)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[4]|this|GM_TDTM_OpportunitiesDuplicateFilter|true|false
00:21:58.59 (626818535)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[4]|this|{}|0x14b84eb4
00:21:58.59 (626830648)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[4]|newlist|List<SObject>|true|false
00:21:58.59 (626861404)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[4]|newlist|[]|0x57852df5
00:21:58.59 (626868029)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[4]|oldlist|List<SObject>|true|false
00:21:58.59 (626877420)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[4]|oldlist|[]|0x1617b800
00:21:58.59 (626883747)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[4]|triggerAction|hed.TDTM_Runnable.Action|true|false
00:21:58.59 (626909334)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[4]|triggerAction|"BeforeUpdate"|0x3e58f0e0
00:21:58.59 (626916902)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[4]|objResult|Schema.DescribeSObjectResult|true|false
00:21:58.59 (627270701)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[4]|objResult|"common.api.soap.wsdl.DescribeSObjectResult@fa2c822f"|0x68c3c471
```

TriggerEntry
[image]

BeforeInsert works fine as expected...

Comment: Check this - https://powerofus.force.com/s/article/EDA-Disable-Trigger-Handlers#ariaid-title4.
Probably it is due to Filter Value

Comment: Yeah removing filter did the trick. Strange why it does that.